# Unity OnCollisionEnter2d not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am having problems getting OnCollisionEnter2d. I am just starting out with Unity and thought I could throw together a simple version of pong just to get started with the basics. In a script I have attached to a ball I have an OnCollisionEnter2d method but it is not being called.

After looking at other posts where people had this problem I have unchecked "Is Kinematic" and set gravity to 0. After unchecking "Is Kinematic" I had to check the x, y and z constraints on the back wall to stop it getting knocked away by the ball. The ball has a "circle collider 2d" component and the wall has a "Box Collider 2d" one. They both have non Kinematic RigidBody2d components. Another answer to a similar question said to check if collisions between different layers was enabled. They are both on the same layer.

I'm sure I have just missed something simple but I am really stumped. This was meant to just be something quick that I threw together before desigining something a little bit meatier. :) If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it. Code and components below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public Text scoreText;
    private int score;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Rigidbody2D rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(1, 1);
        rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
        score = 0;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2d (Collider2D other)
    {
        scoreText.text = "test"; // added this line just to see if the method was being called at all
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BackWall")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[Ball and back wall components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi3pG.jpg)

Sorry I can't paste images inline yet as I don't have the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)

You put OnCollisionEnter2d(Collider2D other)

Unity will not recognize a function if it is misspelled even slightly.

(You would not believe how many times I myself fell prey to this.)

Relevant Link: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Comment: Sorry, I can't believe I missed that considering how many times I checked the syntax. As an aside why didn't the compiler give an error saying that there was no overloaded method that took that argument? Does C# not check that?

Comment: Unity just thought that you were defining your own method, since you spelled it a bit differently. It would have given an error if you spelled the function the same but asked for a different argument.